# Change only hour in datetime column in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

My `datetime` column consists of values like

```
2018-09-01 19:10:06.767
2018-10-25 20:38:58.600
2018-09-16 21:07:33.603
2018-09-02 17:02:03.403
2018-10-20 12:12:52.230
2018-10-07 13:46:20.627
```

I want hours to get changed with 22

What I have tried so far is:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET datecolumn = DATEADD(HOUR, 22, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(datecolumnAS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME))
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"i want hours to get changed with 22 "* Do you mean you want the value of the hour for every datetime to be changed to 22, but leave every other value unchanged?

Comment: yes exactly i want what you said

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want the hours to be `22` with the minutes and seconds, then do:

```
set datecolumn = dateadd(hour,
                         22 - datepart(hour, datecolumn),
                         datecolumn
                        )
```

If you want the time to be `22:00:00`, then you can do:

```
set datecolumn = dateadd(hour, 22,
                         convert(datetime, convert(date, datecolumn))
                        )
```

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is correct, this is what you are after:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET DAteColumn = CONVERT(datetime,STUFF(CONVERT(varchar(25),DateColumn,126),12,2,'22'));
```